# Why should one use FragmentTransaction.commit() at all?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there actually ever a use case for `FragmentTransaction.commit()` where one should not use `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowStateLoss()` instead? The first version almost ever crashes the app in case unexpected things like incoming calls happen, so I'd rather live with some state loss than with a crashed app, wouldn't I?

Comment: "The first version almost ever crashes the app in case unexpected things like incoming calls happen" -- That means that there are bugs in your app. You need to fix the bugs.

Comment: Well, do I need to have any kind of condition / save handler around a commit then? Like, if I process data async I know that I ask in the Fragment for `isAdded()` to ensure that the Fragment's layout is still attached to the activity layout. But if one of the async processes tries to hide a dialog fragment (for example one that shows a progress spinner), what can I do to circumvent hiding the dialog when the activity's save instance state method is already called? Isn't `commitAllowingStateLoss` not what should be used in cases like this?

Comment: "Well, do I need to have any kind of condition / save handler around a commit then?" -- no, because that is not where it is crashing. "But if one of the async processes tries to hide a dialog fragment" -- assuming that you mean "AsyncTask" or "background thread", a background thread should not be messing with fragments. "Isn't commitAllowingStateLoss not what should be used in cases like this?" -- I have never seen a legitimate use of it. All it is doing is hiding an actual bug in your code, one that will have other effects and therefore needs to be fixed.

Comment: If - as part of the result of a background thread - I want to display a dialog fragment or hide one that was displayed until this point, e.g. a progress dialog (all within the UI thread, of course), then what I am usually doing (in the fragment at least) is to ask `isAdded()` and if that returns false  do nothing UI-relevant, because this will either result in NPEs down the line or the aforementioned problem that FragmentTransactions are no longer committable.

Comment: The problem now is that I only have the Activity and not the Fragment available to check what is going on, so what I'm missing is some kind of `Activity.isStateSaved()` or `Activity.isPaused()` method to know "ok, don't mess with the UI / with the fragments, we aren't on screen anyways"...

Comment: ::shrug:: Have the activity hold a `boolean`. Set the `boolean` to `true` in `onPause()`. Set the `boolean` to `false` in `onResume()`. Implement `isPaused()` to return the `boolean`.

Comment: wouldn't `commitAllowingStateLoss` be better in many cases then not showing a dialog at all?  Usually state isn't lost when returning to a previously paused app.  In those cases the user would still see the dialog instead of never seeing it.